# UITableViewController scrolling optimisations for "Messenger App"-like functions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am developing a small app, that includes messenger functionality. When showing a chat thread obviously I used a `tableView`, populate it with the messages in small bubbles and at some point before `viewDidAppear` scroll to the bottom, so the most recent messages are shown.

There is a popular solution to scrolling to the bottom of a `tableView` with `scrollToCellAtIndexPath` or `scrollRectToVisible`. These kinda work with little data, and constant cell heights. BUT in my case there is a lot of message data and I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimensions` for `rowHeight`. This results in slow loading, not scrolling to the bottom and crazy error messages.

**Here's why (IMO):** To scroll to the bottom, the `tableView` has to load all cells because they have automatic dimensions, and can only scroll down after he knows how far it is. Auto layout is another problem. Sometimes it doesn't scroll all the way down, because auto layout didn't finish yet and `rowHeight` is at the initial value still.

**What I tried:** putting the scrolling in `didLayoutSubviews:` solves the problem but loads very slowly, and scrolling is called multiple times (+ some crazy error message)

I guess an upside down `tableView` would solve the problem, because then the first cell could be the latest message, and no scrolling would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For optimization, you should use following method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

It is designed for large data sets, because it provides estimates for calculations instead of pixel-perfect size of cells (you also have to provide normal method for getting height - obviously).

Second optimization that you can do is when you have cells that does not change height with time (that is, they have the same height every time), just store already calculated height for each NSIndexPath and then use this value instead of calculating it again. To get height of the cell with AutoLayout, you can use this:

```
    // Configure it
    self.configureCell(cell!, indexPath: path)

    // Update constraints
    cell!.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell!.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    cell!.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    cell!.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Calculate height of cell
    let height : CGFloat = cell!.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
```

Comment: I did the estimatedRowHeight, but it's not scrolling all the way down. I tried to call the scrollToRow... in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, but scrolls about half way down. If I call it in viewDidAppear it works, but obv. that's too late.

Comment: Thats because in viewWillAppear, TableView is also appearing. Try to call it with delay using perform selector (any delay should work)